# Inherit Tuple in python - ordered tuple

Tags: python, inheritance, tuples

I want to create a class that:

- Has the same behavior as a `tuple`:

  - Immutable elements
  - Has methods `__len__`, `index`, `__getitem__` and so on
- The tuple has only `floats` and it's ordered
- Has a property `qtmin` that counts how many elements are equal to the minimal

So, my idea is to inherit from `tuple`'s class.

```py
class MyTuple(tuple):
    @staticmethod
    def VerifyIsOrdered(U: tuple[float]):
        n = len(U)
        for i in range(n-1):
            if U[i] > U[i+1]:
                raise ValueError("U must be ordered")

    def __init__(self, U: tuple[float]):
        MyTuple.VerifyIsOrdered(U)
        super().__init__(U)

    @property
    def qtmin(self):
        minU = min(self)
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if self[i] != minU:
                return i
    
MyTuple([0, 1, 2, 3])  # qtmin = 1
MyTuple([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3])  # qtmin = 3
```

But I receive the error below at the line `super().__init__(U)`

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

But I don't get what's the problem, cause when I call `super` it's meant to initialize the original `tuple`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Just on a side note.... you don't actually have any float only checking going on there...

Comment: I took out the type verification to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tuple` is immutable, so you need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> **new**() is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also
> commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class
> creation.

```
def __new__(cls, U: tuple[float]):
    MyTuple.VerifyIsOrdered(U)
    return super(MyTuple, cls).__new__(cls, tuple(U))
```

Answer (score 1):

for better syntax, you can use unpacking like this:

```
def __new__(cls,*U):
        MyTuple.VerifyIsOrdered(U)
        return super(MyTuple,cls).__new__(cls,U)
```

so you can write:

```
MyTuple(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

instead of

```
MyTuple([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Just a note: ```tuple(0, 1, 2, 4)``` doesn't work. So I ask myself if this class should have this behavior when its parent doesn't.